# Strange undeletable folder appeared in user home directory

Tags: directory, removing

Something strange happened yesterday: I found a folder in `/home/<user>/` (called `Ak25_gFVIc`) and I deleted it using nautilus. Then, today, I was trying to wipe the trash and the system has gotten stuck. So, I navigate using terminal to `~/.local/share/Trash/files` and there was the folder.

The folder is completely empty but using `ls -l` shows that has a size of 800 MB. I tried deleting it (`rm -rf Ak25_gFVIc/`) with my user and I couldn't remove it (even I own the folder). There was no error message, the terminal just get stuck removing it (`rm -rf Ak25_gFVIc/` + enter and the terminal gets stuck). I have tried the same command using `sudo` and login as superuser using `su` with the the same result. `ls` command into the folder gets stuck too.

Help please!

Comment: Look for the latest updated files under /var/log which might have something specific to this and post the contents of it in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure where the folder came from, but it sounds like you might have some bad sectors on your hard drive. What filesystem is on your hard drive? You can check for bad sectors in [SMART](http://askubuntu.com/a/147712/205638) and try to fix them as in [this answer for ext](http://askubuntu.com/a/299487/205638) and [this answer for NTFS](http://askubuntu.com/a/148885/205638).

Comment: do a `sudo touch /forcecheck` and reboot. The system will start a hard disk check and when done try again to remove the file

Comment: @TheSchwa I have boot into recovery, and I have make a fsck in my hard drive. It's an SSD with a EFI partition, 2 ext4 partitions (`/` and `/home`) and a swap. It doesn't solve it, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Rinzwind done and it didn't work...

Comment: What does `getfacl $HOME/Ak25_gFVIc` tell us ?

Comment: @Serg Solved guys, was a too large directory with lots of directories, waited 5 minutes in an SSD and finally was deleted. Thanks!